# Point domain and sub domain to different CNAME + Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have a Godaddy domain which I want to use for both my API's and website but with different domain and sub domain parameters.

**Domain**: www.testingstack.com

**Sub Domain**: www.api.testingstack.com

Both my api and website are built on 2 different platforms and deployed on Heroku.

I need to know the way to link the above domain and sub domain to my website and api independently.

Comment: Have you already mapped these domains to heroku apps under [Settings](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your_app/settings) page?

Comment: @31piy Yes I have added them.. But will they work independently ?

Comment: Yes they should. Try hitting these URLs and observing the response.

Comment: @31piy One more thing, do I need to mention the DNS name for heroku app in the Domain CNAME of GoDaddy or the Heroku app name

Answer (score 0):

In heroku dashboard, go to **Settings** and find **Domains and Certificates**

[image]